# Solve a linear equation .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

The equation I'm trying to solve is $x+2=x$.

Here's what I tried:

$(x+2)^2=x^2$

$x^2+4x+4=x^2$

$4x=-4$

so $x=-1$

Comment: I don't get what do you mean by the first statement of yours

Comment: Actually what is the Qn?

Answer (score 3):

The statement

> $x=-1$ is a solution of $\langle$an equation$\rangle$

means

> if $x=-1$ then the equation is true.

But you have proved

> if the equation is true then $x=-1$,

which is the **converse** statement and is logically irrelevant.

Comment: Glossing over the impossibility of $x = 2 + x$, I think this is the most on-topic/helpful answer.

Comment: @Newb Thanks!  I was trying to emphasize the fact that there is really no algebraic error in the OP's working, only a logical error.

Comment: @David I follow your three statements.  I will slightly modify your last statement: _if the equation **can** be true, then x = -1_.  If $x = -1$ then the original equation is not satisfied, thus the original equation has no solutions.  But I'm not sure I agree with the term **converse** here or understand the statement about being _"logically irrelevant"_.

Comment: The logical meaning of converse is explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_%28logic%29).

Comment: @David _if the equation is true then x = -1_ is logically correct but this neither proves nor disproves that $x = -1$ is a solution to the original equation.  You must first prove or disprove that the equation _can_ be true for your statement to have any meaning.  What does the predicate, _the equation is true_, mean?  You're completely wrong about the converse being "logically irrelevant"--it's only "irrelevant" because the hypothesis is known to be false--if the hypothesis were true then the converse would have a very _real_ logical relevance (it would prove that $x = -1$ was the solution).

Comment: I'm sorry but you're misusing logic here, because when you say _the equation is true_, I hear $\forall x : x + 2 = x$ which is false for virtually _all_ equations (except ones of the form $x = x$), when we talk about solving equations we are stating that $\exists x: x + 2 = x \leftarrow$ which is a false statement.  So what you are _actually_ saying is that _if false then something_ has no meaning--which I agree with but you have to first prove that your predicate is universally false.

Comment: $$\hbox{"for all real $x$, if $x=-1$ then $x+2=x$" - FALSE}$$ $$\hbox{"for all real $x$, if $x+2=x$ then $x=-1$" - TRUE}$$

Comment: @David I agree that your previous comment is logically correct, but I don't agree that this is explained or even part of your answer.  Where do you prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: x = -1 \rightarrow x+2 = x$ is false?  Your second statement is a trivial "false implies anything" and I don't see what that adds to illuminate the problem (yet your answer seems to imply that the second statement has some meaning--which I don't think it does).  I don't see where you ever prove $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: x = -1 \rightarrow x+2 = x$.

Comment: I have made these statements because they are important.  I have not proved them because I thought it would be a trivial exercise for the reader.  I guess I was wrong in the latter assumption. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The error lies in there cannot exist such a number to begin with, the $x+2=x$ is false from the get go because it is also saying that $2=0$ which is evidently false, as we subtract x from both sides. Doing things to it afterward doesn't change anything to correct it.

I should add however by squaring it you are adding extra possible things as $(-1)^2=1^2$

Comment: There it is a solution because the squares are negating the negative, $(-1)^2=1^2$

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it's possible to take two unequal values, specifically $-x$ and $x$ (assuming $x \neq 0$), and square them to make an equal value.  If you start out with an equation that is universally false, then you can conclude almost anything, for instance in this case, you concluded that $-1 = 1$.

The problem is that you probably were never taught about what an equation actually *means*.  If you are given the following:

$$
f(x) = g(x)
$$

Then before you try and solve it, your *very* first question should be: *does a solution, i.e. $x$, exist!*

In lower level math, it is generally assumed that if you are given a problem to solve that a solution exists so you never really stop and ask yourself whether or not a solution *does* exist.  For instance, find a real value that satisfies the following equation: $x^2 + 1 = 0$...it's *not* possible!

An equation is a boolean statement: $1 = -1$ is a *false*, $2 = 2$ is *true*, $0.01 = 1$ is *false*, etc.  When we say $x + 1 = 0$, we can choose any $x$ we like.  If $x = 1$ then we get $1 + 1 = 2 \neq 0$ so if $x = 1$ then $x + 1 = 0$ is *false*!  When we solve equations we try to find the value of $x$ which makes the statement *true*!

If you start with $x + 2 = x$ then we rearrange to find that $0 = 2$ or $0 = -2$ (or $-1 = 1$, or $-.01 = 1.99$, or $1.5 = -0.5$, etc.--there are infinite amount of rearrangements you could do--all lead to inequality and thus a false statement)--all of which are *false*--unequivocally.  If you try to perform *any* operations on *either* side of that equation it will lead to a false result.

p.s. I don't want to confuse you, so I'm going to keep my wording (of my last sentence) the same.  If I'm being *very* careful, I would say starting with something that is false leads us to an *inconclusive* result (not necessarily a *false* conclusion).  Here is a perfect example: if $x + 2 = 4$ then $x = \frac{4}{2} = 2$--we got the *correct* result, but with faulty reasoning.

Comment: Even if a solution does exist, the procedure is still wrong.  For example, solve $2x=x+1$.  Incorrect answer:$$4x^2=x^2+2x+1\quad\Rightarrow\quad3x^2-2x-1=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=1\ \hbox{or}\ -\tfrac13\ .$$

Comment: @David That's a different situation.  Because you are introducing results that don't satisfy the original equation.  Indeed $x = 1$ _is_ a solution to the original.  I'm not ready to state, unequivocally, that squaring two numbers don't result in the same number, but you _can_ avoid that by simply checking your original equation.  I find your example similar to logarithm problems were we get a quadratic result but we have to discard solutions which result in a negative logarithm of the original equation.

Comment: It is not different, it is exactly the same.  In the OP the original equation had no solution, and an extra solution was introduced ($x=-1$) which did not satisfy the original equation.  In my example the original equation had one solution, and an extra solution was introduced which did not satisfy the original equation.  The essential point is that this error is a logical error, not an algebraic error.

Comment: @David I disagree--it is absolutely different, because in your example, there _was_ a solution and squaring it _still_ found the solution (granted it gave an extra--incorrect--solution).  If you start with an invalid equation, there is no amount of "massaging" that will produce a valid solution.  Yet if you start with a _valid_ equation, any (valid) massaging will _always_ recover a valid solution (even if it produces invalid ones--which can be easily checked for validity against the original).

Comment: Re your last sentence, how do you know what sort of "massaging" is "valid"?  The answer is that "valid massaging" is any operation which can never lead from a correct solution set (including the empty set) to an incorrect solution set.  The last sentence in your comment is therefore a triviality.

Comment: This is also why there is no difference between my example and the OP's.  He went from an empty solution set to an incorrect solution set.  I went from a non-empty solution set to an incorrect solution set.  No difference of any importance.

Comment: And furthermore, if you start with an equation having no solution, you can check all the "solutions" you find and confirm that in fact they are not solutions.  Exactly the same as when you start with an equation which does have solutions.

Comment: @David Then explain to me the steps involved in finding the real values of $x$ which solve the following equation: $\ln(x) + \ln(x + 1) = \ln(2)$.  Because the way I would solve it would be by doing "valid massaging" which leads to one valid answer and one invalid answer which is only realized as invalid after going back to the original equation.

Comment: @David I agree that, after any "valid massaging" (sorry but I'm going to keep using that term until you or I come up with a better one), if that all solutions resulting from that do _not_ satisfy the original equation then there are no solutions to the original equation.  For an example of "invalid massaging", I would point to one of the proofs that [1 = 2](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/falseProofs/first1eq2.html) (in this case they divide by $0$--which is invalid...because if $a = b$ then $a^2 - ab = a^2 - a^2 = 0$).

Comment: I would do exactly as you suggest.  And I would do exactly the same also with $\ln(x)-\ln(x+1)=\ln(2)$, which has no solution.  No difference.

Comment: Re: "valid massaging", no problem with the term, as long as you recognise what it means.

Comment: @David And imo, you presented a problem which is not obviously invalid (although I always hate to use the term "obvious"--because it's basically a code word meaning "I cannot explain why it's obvious") yet through proper "massaging" we come to the _correct_ conclusion that there are no real solutions to the equation $\ln(x) - \ln(x + 1) = \ln(2)$ since it leads us to $x = 2x + 2 \rightarrow x = -2$ which, once plugged in, we realize is not a valid solution of the original equation.

Comment: I think I have lost track of what you are saying.  Your last comment sounds as if you are now agreeing with what I said right at the start - there is no difference between the two situations.

Comment: @David The last half of this was about your statement that _"The answer is that "valid massaging" is any operation which can never lead from a correct solution set (including the empty set) to an incorrect solution set."_  I presented a counterexample to that claim where $\ln(x) + \ln(x + 1) = \ln(2)$ lead to $x^2 + x - 2 = 0 \rightarrow x = 1, -2$ and $x = -2$ was an invalid solution however $x = 1$ _was_ a valid solution (so "valid massaging" still lead us to a correct solution since one existed even though it presented an invalid solution).

Comment: @David If you want to go back to the main point in my answer which is that if you assume a falsity then _you can conclude almost anything_, then it has little to do with algebra and more to do with logic.

Comment: But I didn't say "solution", I said "solution set", that is, the set of **all** solutions.  That's an important point.  Also, I said that "valid massaging" is any operation which can **never** (emphasis added) lead from a correct solution set... to an incorrect solution set.  This does not prevent "invalid massaging" from giving you the right answer if you are lucky.  Famous joke example: simplify $65/26$.  Method: cancel the $6$s.  Answer: $2/5$, correct.

Comment: @David I don't see the distinction (I've made none).  And apparently we do _not_ agree on the term "valid/invalid massaging" because I would consider that $\ln(x^2 + x) = \ln(2)$ to be a valid "massage" and I would consider that $e^{\ln(x^2 + x)} = e^{\ln(2)} \rightarrow x^2 + x = 2$ to be a valid "massage".  First, those _are_ absolutely valid transformations for the value of $x = 2$ and second, you do _not_ realize they are invalid for $x = -1$ until after the fact (i.e. posteriori _not_ a priori).

Comment: The incorrect "massage" is the step from $\ln(x)+\ln(x+1)=\ln(2)$ to $\ln(x^2+x)=\ln(2)$.  This has led you from an equation with one solution to an equation with two solutions and is therefore incorrect, despite the fact that a similar step would give you the correct answer for other questions.  If a step is not **absolutely reliable** - that is, gives you the right answer under **all** circumstances - then it is not valid.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity#Validity_of_arguments) for example.  Once again the point is that this is really a question about logic, not algebra.

Comment: @David Then you don't understand my nuance between knowing something is valid a priori vs. posteriori.  What you are describing is realizing your "massage" was invalid posteriori.  The OP doesn't "realize" that $x + 2 = x \rightarrow (x + 2)^2 = x^2$ is invalid until they see that the result gives an invalid solution (and apparently none of this conversation is going to make any sense since the question has been modified to a quadratic equation).

Comment: @David Perhaps a better example (to make your point) is the equation $x^2 = x\rightarrow x = 1$ (by division by $x$).  In this case we took a valid equation, did some "valid massaging" and correctly came up with a solution but because we did an "invalid massage" we discarded a valid solution (although if we understand that we _cannot_ assume $x = 0$ is _not_ a solution a priori, then we realize dividing by $x$, which _might_ be $0$, is an "invalid massage").

Comment: @David I think this statement of yours explains what we are arguing over: _"He went from an empty solution set to an incorrect solution set. I went from a non-empty solution set to an incorrect solution set. No difference of any importance."_  My disagreement is that this is "no difference of importance".  There is a very real distinction: he went from no solutions to an incorrect solution and in the case of going from a non-empty solution set to an incorrect solution set, you go from _the solutions_ to a group which contains _all_ of the _the solutions_ (and some extraneous non-solutions).

Comment: @David Well, regardless--I think this was an interesting conversation. Instead of "massage"--perhaps operation is the better term (lol). It's interesting because in my example of $x^2 = x$, the operation of dividing by $x$, itself excludes $0$ as an answer--so by dividing by $x$ we are excluding that solution ($x = 0$)--and then indeed, we find all other solutions (i.e. $x = 1$ is the only non-zero solution). Likewise when we say $\ln(x) = \ln(y) \leadsto x = y$ the operation we are doing is specifically excluding $x, y \leq 0$ (for reals, obviously).

Comment: ...of course I couldn't have picked a worse (better?) example than the logarithm since it has infinite solutions for every number (I think--except $0$ which would be undefined) because the actual operation isn't magic, it's the inverse of the logarithm (the exponential function): $e^{\ln(x)} = e^{\ln(y)}$ which leads to many different combinations of $x$ and $y$, not just $x = y$, once we bring in complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

$x+2=x$

$\to$$2=0$ , a contradiction.
Hence there is no solution to the equation $x+2=x$ .

Also $-1$ is the solution of the second degree equation $(x+2)^2=x^2$ and not a solution of the first degree equation  $x+2=x$.